# How to water seal a kitchen sink

Tags: moisture, kitchen-sink

while installing a water filter under the kitchen sink I noticed a damp and rotting section of wood. I followed it up and saw it was being used to secure the kitchen sink from underneath.

There are 2 sinks and only 1 has this problem. I realized there are pieces of wood all around to secure the sinks instead of nuts. Most likely moisture entered through the gap between the sink and counter top because the sealant deteriorated. I moved into this place a few weeks ago so its surprise after surprise - first one was a mound of mouse droppings in a ceiling.

What can I do to fix this and prevent further moisture from spreading? I noticed the cabinet floor right below this is also damp since water droplets periodically trickle down when the sink is in use (confirmed).

I would imagine I'd need to get a new piece of wood and reapply the sealant. Can the sealant be applied w/o removing the sink - through the gaps instead?

Here are helpful pics
[image]

Comment: That piece of wood doesn't look like the proper way to mount a sink. There should be clips fastened to the underside of the countertop that hold the sink in place. There's also clips that can be epoxied to the countertop.

Comment: "water droplets periodically trickle down when the sink is in use" - that shouldn't happen until you fill the sink farther than it ever should be (even if it's well sealed and mounted correctly), which is below that gap. - If you turn the faucet on and it leaks under there, then the faucet leaks or the drain does. If you rent, call and say your sink leaks. If you own it, decide when you want to deal with it for real (actually mount the sink, and prob new faucet). In the meantime, slap some more 100% Si caulk at it, and tighten the drain.

Comment: @mazura I have checked the faucet and drain areas, they are bone dry while the water is running. What I meant by sink being in use is when water is splashing about it trickles down the counter and seeps through the opening under it. The piece of wood is directly under it and after examining it further, offers no support to the sink since it feels like sludge. I own this place and will examine the task further.

Comment: @PlatinumGoose is this what you're referring to? https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/71NsitFIk+L._AC_SL1500_.jpg

There is very little room around 3 out of 4 sides of the sink. I may be able to only attach one sink clip in the corner. There is perhaps 1.5" gap b/w sinks where the counter is visible. I do see the functional benefit of this clips.

Comment: Yes those are one style of clips. You can probably find smaller clips but they may be the type that require you to drill a hole in the countertop. You may need to remove the sink to drill the holes. If the epoxy clips will fit I would use those.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with not removing/dropping the sink to apply the sealant, is that every time you wash/wipe there, you can peel off/remove some of the sealant.

It will only be on the surface.

It should be much faster and last for a long time if done right.

Drop the sink and clean off all of the old sealant from sink and bottom of counter.  Place new sealant and re install the sink.

Comment: In addition to sealant, it appears that there needs to be additional physical mounting added to this back edge of the sink. That may involve drilling holes into the bottom of the counter top to attach clips to. Doing it the _right_ way is also often the most difficult and inconvenient way. It does, however, offer the benefit of being longest lasting solution _because_ it's the right way. +1